# Error when deploying ear to Weblogic 12c

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm developing simple web page using Jdeveloper 11g and weblogic server 12c.
i have one ejb jar which contains EJBs and one more jar contains Entities and one more war contains web pages and managed beans. That managed beans call and work with the ejbs.

but when i deploying them in weblogic server it gives me following error:

```
<Feb 28, 2012 5:20:38 PM ULAT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Error: Unresolved Webapp Library references for       
"WebAppModule(IBIForum:IBIForum-view-context-root)", defined in weblogic.xml [Extension-  Name:     
jstl, Specification-Version: 1.2, exact-match: false], [Extension-Name: jsf,     Specification-Version: 2, exact-match: false]
at   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.mergeWebAppLibraries(WebAppModule.java:472)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.processWebAppLibraries(WebAppModule.java:440)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:256)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:636)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace >
```

Answer (score 3):

Your application is flagged as dependent on JSF 2 in WebLogic 12c, but since WLS 12c comes already with JSF 2 incorporated, this flag shouldn't be necessary.  I suggest you review the libraries used by your application in JDev app properties.

> As of WebLogic Server 12.1.1, JSF 2.x and JSTL 1.2 have been
>   incorporated directly in the server's classpath. Your applications
>   deployed to WebLogic Server can seamlessly make use of JSF 2.x and
>   JSTL 1.2 without requiring you to deploy and reference separate shared
>   libraries, as was the case in previous releases.

[See docs for WebLogic 12.1.2 - 6 Using JSF and JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WBAPP/configurejsfandjtsl.htm#WBAPP198)

Although, since you are deploying on WLS 12c I also strongly suggest you to use JDeveloper 12c or OEPE 12c instead of JDev 11g. The previous version of JDev is not certified to work with WLS 12c and may be the reason you are getting this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Weblogic ships with implementations of both jsf 1.2 and 2. You may have to deploy one of them as a library and reference it as a shared lib

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing the JSTL 1.2  library. Follow this to install it : Go into your server , click on install new Application/Library , then select the the path to Oracle-> Middleware-> wlserver-> common-> deployable-libraries and select the JSTL 1.2. or JSF 2.0  library . It worked for me